# library function to set nth element of a list

Tags: list, ocaml

Is there a library function to do something like this `set_elem` declaration?

```
set_elem (l : int list) (i : int) (x : int) : int list
```

For example:

```
(set_elem [1; 2; 3; 4] 1 90)
```

would return:

```
[1; 90; 3; 4]
```

Answer (score 2):

There isn't, and that's likely because direct indexing is a pretty bad use case for an immutably linked list, with costs that aren't properly reflected by such convenience functions. If you find yourself doing this often, you should consider using an array instead.

That said, the easiest way I can think of is to use `List.mapi` to return the new element only if we're at the right index, and the existing element otherwise:

```
List.mapi (fun i el -> if i = 1 then x else el) l
```

Or as a function with your desired signature:

```
let set_elem (l : int list) (i : int) (x : int) : int list =
  List.mapi (fun i' el -> if i = i' then x else el) l
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, if you want to use a mutable data structure, the `Array` module can do exactly that.

```
let a = [|1; 2; 3; 4|];;
(* val a : int array = [|1; 2; 3; 4|] *)

Array.set a 1 90;;
(* - : unit = () *)

a;;
(* - : int array = [|1; 90; 3; 4|] *)
```

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't a library function in the standard [List](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/List.html) library, but it isn't too tough to code one up.

Here is a non tail-recursive implementation.

```
(** [insert n el lst] inserts element [el] in the [n]th position in the 
    list [lst].
    Raises: [Failure] if index is out of bounds *)
let rec insert n el lst =
  match n,lst with 
  | i, _ when i >= List.length lst -> failwith "Index out of Bounds"
  | _, [] -> []
  | 0, _::t -> el::(insert (-1) el t)
  | i, h::t -> h::(insert (i-1) el t)
```

The idea is to pattern match against `n` and `lst` together.

If you hit the empty list, then return the initial value (or accumulator if you want a tail recursive solution).

If `n` hits 0, then append the element to the list and continue going through the rest of the list to preserve the other elements (but make sure you never hit 0 again, that is why I used the `-1`).

Otherwise, you add the old elements of the list until `n` hits 0.

Answer (score 0):

The other solutions run in `O(n)` time (where `n` is the length of the list), when you really only need your solution to run in `O(i)` time (where `i` is your index).

Here's an efficient tail-recursive function:

```
let set l ~i ~data =
  let rec helper ~prev_rev ~curr ~i =
    match curr, i with
    | []        , _ -> List.rev prev_rev
    | _  :: curr, 0 -> List.rev_append prev_rev (data :: curr)
    | hd :: curr, _ -> helper ~prev_rev:(hd :: prev_rev) ~curr ~i:(i - 1)
  in
  if i < 0 || i >= List.length l
  then l
  else helper ~prev_rev:[] ~curr:l ~i
```

This function does not change `l` if you pass in an invalid index. You can change this to raise an exception if you'd like.